# Core Data Search predicate not searching symbols in predicate

Tags: swift, core-data

Trying to implement a search feature into my application. The basic search function for regular card names containing no symbols works but, I have a few cards with names that contain symbols that don't search even if you put the appropriate card name in containing those symbols. Also having some slight difficulty trying to have it so when the text field is empty the full list returns. The search I have implemented is:

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)

    let requiredClassName = passedDeckObject!.classSelected.classname
    var requiredCardClasses = [Int]()
    switch(requiredClassName) {
    case "Warrior":
        requiredCardClasses = [1,10]
    case "Shaman":
        requiredCardClasses = [2,10]
    case "Rogue":
        requiredCardClasses = [3,10]
    case "Paladin":
        requiredCardClasses = [4,10]
    case "Hunter":
        requiredCardClasses = [5,10]
    case "Druid":
        requiredCardClasses = [6,10]
    case "Warlock":
        requiredCardClasses = [7,10]
    case "Mage":
        requiredCardClasses = [8,10]
    case "Priest":
        requiredCardClasses = [9,10]
    default:
        requiredCardClasses = [10]
    }


    if !searchText.isEmpty {
        // Clear out the fetchedResultController

        // Setup the fetch request
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Cards")
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 50
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .AndPredicateType, subpredicates: [NSPredicate(format: "name contains[cd] %@", searchText), NSPredicate(format: "cardClass IN %@", requiredCardClasses)])
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        //end//


        //cost fetch request begins here//
        let costfetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "cardCost")
        costfetchRequest.fetchLimit = 50
        costfetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "cardCost = %i", searchText)
        let costSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "cardCost", ascending: true)
        costfetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        //end//


        // Pass the fetchRequest and the context as parameters to the fetchedResultController
        frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext!,
            sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        // Make the fetchedResultController a delegate of the MoviesViewController class
        frc.delegate = self
        // Execute the fetch request or display an error message in the Debugger console
        var error: NSError? = nil
        if (!frc.performFetch(&error)) {
            println("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
        // Refresh the table view to show search results
        cardsListed.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Show some examples. What error is returned? How are you testing it?

Comment: No error returned it just isn't actually displaying any objects that contain any form of symbols for instance I have a instance where a name is split by a ' called al'akir. If al is put in the search it finds the object but if the person puts al' or anything beyond no objects are returned.

Comment: Print the predicate after each edit, the predicate should handle escaping quote marks

Comment: Right now as each letter is put in it does update it just doesn't actually accept any symbols inputed.

Comment: Ok, but what does the predicate log when you put a symbol in the search text ?

Comment: It logs no objects at all. All objects disappear from the tableview.

Comment: Optional(name CONTAINS[cd] "a" AND cardClass IN {1, 10})
Optional(name CONTAINS[cd] "al" AND cardClass IN {1, 10})
Optional(name CONTAINS[cd] "al'" AND cardClass IN {1, 10})
Optional(name CONTAINS[cd] "al'a" AND cardClass IN {1, 10})
Optional(name CONTAINS[cd] "al'ak" AND cardClass IN {1, 10})
Optional(name CONTAINS[cd] "al'aki" AND cardClass IN {1, 10})
Optional(name CONTAINS[cd] "al'akir" AND cardClass IN {1, 10})

Comment: Looks ok, so i'd guess the data in the store is actually a different character - compare the UTF codes for the characters in the search text and those in the model

Comment: interesting I will have to go figure it out i guess.